# VPS IP redirects to website instead of the IP directory? CentOs 6

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, ip-address, centos-6, vps

So before I started putting websites on my VPS, I could access the IP directly and it would access the html folder in the /var/www/ area. But ever since I placed websites on the VPS, I can no longer access that HTML folder, it goes to the first domain I have listed on the httpd.conf file.

Is there a way I can make the IP its self look like a website in the httpd conf file? I tried to construct it like the other websites but httpd would stop working.

Comment: HTML is one of the few protocols which sends the hostname along with the requests. So trying to get to webpage http://1.2.3.4/ is not the same as trying to view http://some.page.net/. I can appear the same if the web server only has one domain. E.g. it might serve the first (and only) domain in that case. This is why you run into your problem.

Comment: @Hennes A better example of this is [198.252.206.16](http://198.252.206.16) vs [superuser.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3asuperuser.com&run=toolpage). All stack exchange sites (that I have checked) are hosted on 198.252.206.16